# Product of matrices with positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ have positive eigenvalues. Does it follow that $AB$ must have positive eigenvalues as well? Note that $A$ and $B$ are not assumed to be symmetric.

Comment: Have you tried to do some numerical experiments (with $2\times2$ matrices, for instance) and see if the hypothesis is true or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt2\big/2&0\\\sqrt2\big/2&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$. Their product $AB$ is a rotation by 45 degrees. So $(AB)^4 = -I$ which ought to have positive eigenvalues if your hypothesis were true.

Comment: Found by fiddling around with products of upper and lower triangular matrices and looking for something that could be used to produce a rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Not always, counter example (Using Matlab) : 
let $$  A = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{array} } \right] ,  B = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 12 & 8 \\ 9 & 10 \\ \end{array} } \right]  $$ $ A$ has a double eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, while $B$ have eigenvalues $\lambda = 19.544$ and $\lambda = 2.456$.
but $$  AB = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 12 & -28 \\ 9 & -17 \\ \end{array} } \right]  $$ have complex eigenvalues : $ \lambda = -2.5000 \pm 6.4614i $.

Comment: I think it'd be great to explain how you found those matrices.

Comment: I found the matrix $A$ and $B$...by googling..